# get_object() that depends on `request` in UpdateView

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I am writing a class-based view to allow users to edit their profile. Since I want the users to access this view with a URL of the type `my_profile/edit/` rather than something like `profile/<int:pk>/edit/`, using a view based on `UpdateView` is quite cumbersome since getting the user profile object requires to access the `request` object, and `get_object` does not directly have access to it.

My two questions:

- Shall I use `UpdateView` in this case?
- If so, what would be the best way to override `get_object(self, queryset=None)`? My best attempt so far is the following:

  ```
  class EditProfileView(UpdateView):
      model = UserProfile
      _request = None

      def get_object(self, queryset=None):
          return get_user_profile(self._request)

      def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs): # can also override setup() in newer Django versions
          self._request = request
          return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  ```

This looks clean enough to me except that if one day the Django framework decides that `get_object` should be called early in the workflow of the view generation, this piece of code could break.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do this. All class-based views make the request available as `self.request`.

Your entire code should just be:

```
class EditProfileView(UpdateView):
    model = UserProfile

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return get_user_profile(self.request)
```

Note, even if it didn't, you still wouldn't need to define `_request` at class level. That's just not necessary in Python.

Also, I don't know what your `get_user_profile` function does but it can probably be replaced with just `self.request.user.profile`.

Comment: Ah, yes! I didn't know that `request` was in the attributes! Looking at the Django code it is even defined very early (before `dispatch` is called, in Django 2.0).